# How do I use react-table with own data?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, memoization, react-table

I am using react-table and followed along with the example https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/basic Everything worked as expected.  However when I try and use my own data, I keep getting TypeError: data is undefined in useTable.  My array does contain the key id and I am able to view the items array in the console. If I use a predefined array as in the example, it works just fine

```
const [items, setItems] = useState(() =>{
    let init = new Array(0)
    for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        init.push(collections[0].items[i])
    }
        
    return init;
})
    
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
        {
            Header: 'ID',
            accessor: 'id',
        },
    ], [],
);
    
const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
} = useTable({ columns, items }, useSortBy);  <----- ERROR HERE
```

edit:

I think the issue is that the items array has o be memoized but how would I do this?

edit 2:

So maybe this wasn't the issue. I changed my useState to:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState(React.useMemo(() =>{
    let init = new Array(0)
    for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        init.push(collections[0].items[i])
    }

    return init;
}, []))
```

but I still get the TypeError: data is undefined. When I console.log items, it has the correct data in it.

Comment: You have to pass `data` to `useTable` not `items`. `useTable({ columns, data: items }, useSortBy)`

Answer (score 2):

I spent hours trying to figure this out and the answer is pretty lame. The array has to be called data. I just renamed items to data and it worked.

Comment: ok, you have saved my day. Have been looking for the sulotion about 2 days... that's the one